# how to get git commit history for a subfolder and all files under the folder ONLY?

Tags: git

for example I want to know all changes made on a certain subfolder or maybe a specific file. Is there a command line to do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run: `git log -- path/to/directory`
or (if you want a GUI):
`gitk -- path/to/directory`